# The concept of DDR rank

Tags: digital-logic, memory, computer-architecture, ddr

I have an understanding of DDR rank which I think is incorrect. If someone could join the dots then there would be more clarity.

Here is what I know

1. A DDR rank is a 64bit interface consisting of x8 or x16 devices
2. Each rank is controlled by an individual CS. So two ranks means 2 CS signals to control them
3. A CA bus is shared among devices of different ranks. Two devices in the same rank don't share the CA bus.
   All of the confusion started when I saw the following images based on which I have few questions
   [image: Single Rank]

In the above image as the CA bus is not shared, both the devices are on the same rank.

1. So does that mean external to the package the CS pins have to be shorted i.e CS0_A and CS0_B should be controlled by 1 CS pin from the controller?
2. If we keep the CS pins separate and don't short them, doesn't that make the operation dual rank?
3. Is an x32 bit interface from a package enough to constitute a rank?

[image: Dual rank]

Here is a dual-rank package from which I concluded that CA buses must be shared among devices of different ranks.

1. So in the dual-rank package should we have only 2 bit CS to control the two ranks or can we have a separate CS control for each device in the 2 rank config?

The rank concept is highly confusing hence the questions.

Comment: "Two devices in the same rank don't share the CA bus." -- share or don't share? Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I just started reading into the matter. Here is my interpretation:

> 1. A DDR rank is a 64bit interface consisting of x8 or x16 devices

I agree with this one. The data bus width is split to several physical chips.

> 2. Each rank is controlled by an individual CS. So two ranks means 2 CS signals to control them

Yes. And all physical chips within the rank are connected to the same CS for this rank.

> 3. A CA bus is shared among devices of different ranks. Two devices in the same rank don't share the CA bus.

I assume CA is the address bus, then yes.
But the address bus **is** shared across devices of different ranks. Hence your observation:

> [...]  from which I concluded that CA buses must be shared among devices of different ranks.

See the following image (that I made) for an example that I came up with:
(note that only 16 bits of the total 64 bits are shown)

- the 16 bits from the data bus are split into 4x 4 bits
- the 21 address bits are shared between ranks and devices
- multiplexing (serialization) between the two ranks is done via CS signals

[image: Example of a 2 Rank, 4x parallelized DRAM]

Now regarding your confusion about the datasheet images.
The first image shows a "Dual-Die, **Dual-Channel**, **Single-Rank** Package".
See the keyword "Dual-Channel" which means that there is not just a single 64 bit channel to the CPU. So you need two individual address inputs.
In my opinion you could also use this as a "**Single-Channel**, **Dual-Rank**" device by physically connecting the address inputs to a single address bus.